# resources folder is not getting found in eclipse with InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("resources/template.properties");

Tags: java

I have an awt application which will be run using executable JAR file. Few Issues I am facing in getting resources folder

**1. In Eclipse, If I use following code**

```
    properties = new Properties();
    InputStream in =getClass().getResourceAsStream("resources/template.properties"); 
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

Then I am getting

```
 ERROR   2019-11-11 12:03:44,052 [AWT-EventQueue-0] 
 java.lang.NullPointerException
```

If I use the above code in eclipse and when I export runnable Jar then it is working in JAR file but when I run in eclipse it is throwing nullpointer exception.

**Case 2:** But if I use below code and export JAR file then JAR file is throwing error as "in current directory resources is not available" even resources folder is present.

```
properties = new Properties();
InputStream in = 
inputStream = new FileInputStream("resources/template.properties");
```

Folder structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBU9N.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't reference the **resource** folder in the file path string. But then, your **resource** folder needs to be a source folder for Eclipse.

I don't know your project strcuture yet, but I suggest you to create a **resource** folder on your project root, then rigth click on it and go to **Build Path > Use As a Source Folder**.

After that, all files inside that folder will both be directly accessed by the *getResourceAsStream* method, and also be placed on the JAR root, merged with all other files from the other source folders.

Then you can do:

```
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("template.properties");
```

This way should work both inside Eclipse and in the standalone JAR.

PS: I strongly suggest you to start using Maven projects and follow its folder structure.

Comment: Thank You. Please see above folder structure that is been used. I have two problems 
1]  My resource folder is not getting included as in the JAR package. I have to copy it manually in the JAR package. But if I remove config file from the folder and even though that is present in resources folder (which I copied manually) then JAR is giving exception i.e. NullPointer

Comment: The idea of a resources folder is to contain files that will be placed directly to the JAR root folder. You should not have a resources folder inside the JAR. It is a folder of your code project, but it is not a fodler of the compiled program. That's why you shuld tell eclipse to "Use As a Source Folder"

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the `resources` path if you do like this snippet bellow it might work.

```java
InputStream inputStream = getClass()
            .getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("template.properties");
```